# Searching via loop from one text file to another in python, whilst returning only one result per search item

Tags: python, loops

**The Problem:**

I have a text file, which contains different names of species on each line, I will include an example below, I have another line which has a list of file paths and species names (also included below). I would like to find each example of a species in the first list present in the second list (with the file path returned), but only one for each species return for each species. At the moment my code finds the first species on the list, and returns each instance of that and then stops.

**Example Input:**

Here is a subset of the species name text file:

```
Ferroglobus placidus
Halorubrum arcis
Sulfolobus acidocaldarius
```

Here is a subset of the directory and species name file:

```
file,Species
./refseq/archaea/GCF_001560525.1/GCF_001560525.1_NG05B_C06_12_genomic,Sulfolobus acidocaldarius
./refseq/archaea/GCF_001560525.1/GCF_001560525.1_NG05B_C06_12_genomic,Sulfolobus acidocaldarius
./refseq/archaea/GCF_001560525.1/GCF_001560525.1_NG05B_C06_12_genomic,Sulfolobus acidocaldarius
./refseq/archaea/GCF_001560525.1/GCF_001560525.1_NG05B_C06_12_genomic,Sulfolobus acidocaldarius
./refseq/archaea/GCF_000337015.1/GCF_000337015.1_ASM33701v1_genomic,Halorubrum arcis
./refseq/archaea/GCF_000337015.1/GCF_000337015.1_ASM33701v1_genomic,Halorubrum arcis
./refseq/archaea/GCF_000337015.1/GCF_000337015.1_ASM33701v1_genomic,Halorubrum arcis
./refseq/archaea/GCF_000337015.1/GCF_000337015.1_ASM33701v1_genomic,Halorubrum arcis
./refseq/archaea/GCF_000025505.1/GCF_000025505.1_ASM2550v1_genomic,Ferroglobus placidus
./refseq/archaea/GCF_000025505.1/GCF_000025505.1_ASM2550v1_genomic,Ferroglobus placidus
./refseq/archaea/GCF_000025505.1/GCF_000025505.1_ASM2550v1_genomic,Ferroglobus placidus
./refseq/archaea/GCF_000025505.1/GCF_000025505.1_ASM2550v1_genomic,Ferroglobus placidus
```

**Current code:**
The code at the moment loops once for the first name on the species list, and then stops.

```
import re
import sys

list = open('speciesnames.txt', "r")

file = open('pathandspeciesname.csv', "r")


for x in list:
    for line in file:
        if re.findall(x, line):
            print (line)
```

**Current Output:**

Here is an example of the output I get from the code above, each instance of Ferroglobus placidus is returned, but the loop stops after that.

```
./refseq/archaea/GCF_000025505.1/GCF_000025505.1_ASM2550v1_genomic,Ferroglobus placidus

./refseq/archaea/GCF_000025505.1/GCF_000025505.1_ASM2550v1_genomic,Ferroglobus placidus

./refseq/archaea/GCF_000025505.1/GCF_000025505.1_ASM2550v1_genomic,Ferroglobus placidus
```

**Desired output:**
My desired output is to have a path for each species, but only one for each species, such as below:

```
./refseq/archaea/GCF_001560525.1/GCF_001560525.1_NG05B_C06_12_genomic,Sulfolobus acidocaldarius
./refseq/archaea/GCF_000337015.1/GCF_000337015.1_ASM33701v1_genomic,Halorubrum arcis
./refseq/archaea/GCF_000025505.1/GCF_000025505.1_ASM2550v1_genomic,Ferroglobus placidus
```

Comment: *"my code finds the first species on the list"*: You couldn't `loop` a filehandle more than **once** without reseting the read pointer. But your approach, reading file contents more than once, is bad at all. I recommend to use `pandas`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

listofspecies = open("allspeciesfull.txt").readlines()

listoffiles = open("fileid4.csv").readlines()



for x in listofspecies:
    for line in listoffiles:
        if re.findall(x, line):
            print (line)
            break
```

Using the `break` function means the loop only works once per if statement, using the `readlines` function means lists are being used rather than filehandles.